# Posso criar modulos em asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho uma pagina home com contato e tal, igual a outras paginas. Na pagina eu tenho um button de Login e quando eu clicar no mesmo redirecionar para um modulo do projeto.

Exemplo:
Home
localhost/Principal/Home/Index

Login
localhost/EAD/Login/Index

Seriam dois projetos diferentes, tem como eu trabalhar dessa forma com o asp.net MVC?

Na hospedagem por exemplo eu poderia fazer o deploy de duas aplicações sem uma destruir a outra? Alguém sabe quantas aplicação eu posso ter uma hospedagem simples de asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deivid, na verdade você nem precisa criar vários projetos. Você pode separar os **Módulos** por [`Area`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) no *ASP.NET MVC 4*. Nas verdade esse conceito existe desde a versão 1.0 do ASP.NET MVC.

Caso você não conheça o conceito ou nunca tenha trabalhado com isso, basta seguir o [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Obrigado! Estou vendo o artigo. Para quem não manja muito inglês segue o link de um artigo do macoratti. http://www.macoratti.net/15/07/mvc5_area1.htm